# Express 4 rest api routes in a subfolder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I cant seem to get my .get('/:post_id) route to work and i have no idea why...

my folder structure is like this:

- app.js
- routes
- --api
- ----blog.js

essentially blog.js is in the routes/api folder

in app.js i have this:

```js
var blog = require('./routes/api/blog');

app.use('/api/blog', blog);
```

in blog.js i have this:

```js
//ALL API calls at /api/blog/:post_id
    router.route('/:posts_id')

    //Retrieve and individual post in JSON by id
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Post.findById(req.params.posts_id, function(err, post) {
            if (err) {
                res.send("error");
            } else {
                res.json(post);
            }
        });
    });
```

there is a get and post request in the same folder and they work fine, but i end up with a 404 error from the app.js file and it never even reaches the :posts_id route... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you should change **blog.js**

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router
    .get('/:posts_id', function (req, res, next) {
        res.send("i am here")    // in here when request /api/blog/:post_id
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: So i tried this, but it doesnt seem to work... thats pretty much the same as i have, except it removes the '/api' part of the app.use require statement. doing so crashes my server as no module exists at ./routes/blog. Thanks though

Comment: api.js and blog.js are same directory? I don't know why you write var blog = require('./routes/api/blog'); -> like blog.js is place in api directory.

Comment: are you missing export module? module.exports = router;

Comment: the folder structure is like this /routes/api/blog.js

Comment: i have the export module like that as well... in the blog.js file my get request on '/' works

Comment: if blog.js place in api directory see my update code above. Then you need fix folder structure in your question. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112558/discussion-between-cameron-johnston-and-kibgzr).

Comment: i figured this out, i just had a misplaced }); that was wrapping the routes and causing an issue... thanks for the help though